Intermittent Network Printer Issues with Kyocera Devices Across VLANs
We're experiencing an intermittent issue with our network printers (primarily Kyocera) in our company. The problem is that the printers randomly stop working for certain users on a day-to-day basis. Out of 10 users, 9 can print without any issues, but one cannot, and the affected printer varies each day.
Here's our setup:

Printers are on VLAN 120 with reserved IPs.
Our print server is on VLAN 100.
Clients are on VLAN 170.

We've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

Checking DNS and DHCP configurations, which appear to be correct.
Ensuring firewall rules are not causing the issue (we've even
disabled IPS for testing). Verifying the cabling.

Sometimes, restarting the local spooler service on the client side resolves the issue, but occasionally, the spooler restart takes a long time and fails to connect to the printer, suggesting a server spooler restart is needed.
However, the server always maintains a connection to the printers and shows them as "Ready," and printing directly from the server works without issues.
We've also performed packet captures but couldn't identify anything noteworthy.
We're running out of ideas and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what could be causing this inconsistent printer availability.

Sometimes, restarting the local spooler service on the client are the clients configured to print to the print server or directly to the printer?

The Clients are configured to spool on the server

Are the drivers Microsoft signed? What versions and details like V4 are we talking?

@GregAskew We mostly have Type 3 - User Mode Drivers, how can i check if they are ms signed on the print server?

The properties of the driver UI should show it, typically one of the files.

Ah got you - so basically all drivers have the value true under the packages column and as driver isolation Shared (For the Kyoceras), Provider is Kyocera itself and Microsoft for the in house Printers (like pdf printer, etc)
